# Where should I create a new entity field Dynamics CRM 2016?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online

I'm working on Dynamics CRM online 2016, the requirement is to create a new entity field inside all the entities that we have in a third party vendor solution (unmanaged).
I'm wondering what is the way to solve this requirement. Because that Solution is huge and it has more than 20 entities. 
The third party vendor told me that I have to create a new solution and add all the entities to this new solution and then add the field in each entity. I guess that they want to keep separately new configurations and customizations.
However, my boss told me; you are free to choose working in that solution (third party solution) or to create a new one.

I think it's better and easier to work in the third party solution (because at the end, when I need to migrate these changes to our other instances, I will export and import this solution), however I'm fairly new in Dynamics and in terms of migration process, I do not know what is the best approach.

I really appreciate any suggestion from you guys.

Answer (score 2):

It is fine to work in the third party solution, which I would recommend. If for some reason you prefer, it is also fine to work from a new solution you create.

The key is to understand that solutions do not really matter: The entities themselves exist in the layer of unmanaged customizations of the system. Solutions are simply containers that point to these unmanaged entities.

No matter how many solutions you have that point to a given entity, any modification made will be made directly to the entity.

Since you are using CRM 2016 you have the possibility of choosing which fields from an entity to include in your solution. This could be used if you for some reason really want to have one solution with and one solution without your newly added field.

MSDN has the following note about having [multiple solutions with shared components:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334353.aspx)

> Some components can be included in more than one solution as long as
>   any changes that were made to them are compatible with all other
>   solutions that use them. It is important that all the solutions share
>   the same solution publisher. If the solution publisher is not
>   identical, organizations will not be able to install more than one of
>   your solutions.